# How to get the string with expect_out (Linux)?

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I have the following string:

```
abc xyz: -123.456789

qwertyuiopxxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
```

I want to get only the number (-123.456) in that string with expect_out, can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string is being fed to you from a `spawn`ed process:

```
expect {
    -re {abc xyz:\s+(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)} {
        set value $expect_out(1,string)
        puts "I have just got $value"
    }
}
```

There's definitely a knack to writing a good regular expression.